# How do I create an alias for a .jar command-line script?

Tags: java, macos, command-line, apache-fop, bash

I've got a `jar` file that can be run from the command line like this:

```
# In Terminal.app
java -jar fop.jar /path/to/infile.fo /path/to/outfile.pdf
```

At the moment for this to work I need to navigate to the folder containing *fop.jar*. This isn't ideal, so I've tried to add the following *alias* to `bash_profile`...

```
# In bash_profile
alias fop="java -jar /path/to/a/far/away/folder/fop-2.1/build/fop.jar"
```

...with the hope that I could execute this script from the Desktop (or anywhere else) like so:

```
# In Terminal
fop ~/Desktop/simple.fo ~/Desktop/simple.pdf
```

Unfortunately it's not working:

```
# Error message
Unable to start FOP:
java.lang.RuntimeException: fop.jar not found in directory: /my/pwd (or below)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.getJARList(Main.java:70)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOPWithDynamicClasspath(Main.java:130)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:219)
```

---

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you run the alias command in the actual folder containing fop.jar does it work?

Comment: @Michael: It does.

Answer (score 1):

An alias or a function should work fine as long as the real path of `java` and `fop.jar` is used:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

If you wanted to create a function (which has the benefit of allowing you to change options, parameters, arguments, etc.) you could add something such as this to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# fop: run java -jar with input and output files
fop () { /usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/fop.jar "$1" "$2" ; }
```

The key ingredient is telling the function or alias the path of your `java` executable and `fop.jar`. Another thing that might help resolve the issue is to create a symlink to `fop.jar` someplace convenient, then you can easily reference it as needed.

```
ln -s /path/to/fop.jar /path/to/symlink
```

So by doing that your command would essentially would become:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/symlink infile outfile
```

↳ [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)